# Javascript filter function is not working proeprly

Tags: javascript

I have an object which contains two signals. `(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID` and `(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype`. Now user might want to see either trainID or Traintype. hence I have implemented this function:

my object look like this:

```
var myarray = [{
  "captions": [
    {
      "name": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID",
      "attributes": {},
      "filter": true,
      "sort": true
    },
    {
      "name": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype",
      "attributes": {},
      "filter": true,
      "sort": true
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1002,
          "hiddenValue": 1002,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1002,
          "hiddenValue": 1002,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "direction": "vertical",
  "attributes": {},
  "clickable": false
}]
```

my function look like this:

```
   function myfilter (value) {
        var afterfilter = myarray.filter(data=>{
      console.log(data)
        return data['rows'].filter(cells=>{ 
            return cells['cells'].filter(d=>{       
            return cells.toString().toLowerCase().includes("trainid".toLowerCase())             
          })
        })
      })
      console.log(afterfilter)
    }

myfilter()
```

Now how can i modify my function so that it can do the partial search and find the respective object both for captions and rows.

So after filtering the object, i should contains the data only for  `(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID` and myarray should look like this:

```
var myarray = [{
  "captions": [
    {
      "name": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID",
      "attributes": {},
      "filter": true,
      "sort": true
    }],
    "rows": [{
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        } ]
    }, and so on
```

so the array will not contain any object related to `(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype`

How can i modify the function to achieve this.

```js
var myarray = [{
  "captions": [
    {
      "name": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID",
      "attributes": {},
      "filter": true,
      "sort": true
    },
    {
      "name": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype",
      "attributes": {},
      "filter": true,
      "sort": true
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1002,
          "hiddenValue": 1002,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1002,
          "hiddenValue": 1002,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "direction": "vertical",
  "attributes": {},
  "clickable": false
}]



function myfilter (value) {
 var afterfilter = myarray.filter(data=>{
  console.log(data)
   return data['rows'].filter(cells=>{ 
     return cells['cells'].filter(d=>{       
       return cells.toString().toLowerCase().includes("id".toLowerCase())          
      })
    })
  })
  console.log(afterfilter)
}

myfilter()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to deal with them separately ...

Here's something that will work.

```js
var myarray = [{
  "captions": [
    {
      "name": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID",
      "attributes": {},
      "filter": true,
      "sort": true
    },
    {
      "name": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype",
      "attributes": {},
      "filter": true,
      "sort": true
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1002,
          "hiddenValue": 1002,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1002,
          "hiddenValue": 1002,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "ICE",
          "hiddenValue": "ICE",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": 1000,
          "hiddenValue": 1000,
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_TrainID"
        },
        {
          "value": "IC",
          "hiddenValue": "IC",
          "type": "data",
          "columnName": "(2)(2) Sheet1_Traintype"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "direction": "vertical",
  "attributes": {},
  "clickable": false
}]




function myfilter (value) {
 return value.map(obj => {
    return {captions: (obj.captions.filter(c => c.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes("id".toLowerCase()))), rows: obj.rows.map(row => {
      return {cells:row.cells.filter(c => c.columnName.toString().toLowerCase().includes("id".toLowerCase()))}
    })}
  })
}

console.log(myfilter(myarray))
```

Comment: I have fixed the solution .. (forgot about putting cells index at first.)

Comment: having error, (index):206 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' @anees-ijaz